# Topology of the boundary of union of polydisks

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, symplectic-geometry, contact-topology, contact-geometry

For $a,b> 0$, define the symplectic polydisk $P(a,b)\subset \mathbb{C}^2$ as the set of points $(z_1,z_2)$ s.t.
$$|z_1|^2\leq a, |z_1|^2\leq b.$$
Notice that the boundary of $P(a,b)$ is topologically $S^3$.

I would like to know, topollogically speaking, what is the boundary of $P(2,1)\cup P(1,2)$. I know that is either $S^3$ or a solid torus  with its 2-dim boundary, but it is still not clear to me which one of those. I would appreciate any insight.

Comment: Hint: The union is starlike.

Comment: But still, I don't see how this necessarily implies that the boundary must be homeomorphic to $S^3$ (I think this is tru in lower dimensions but maybe not here). I've been looking for a proof of that in the internet and haven't found one. Could you eleaborate @MoisheKohan?

Comment: The idea is not to look for a proof online but to think about it. What is the definition of a compact starlike set? How does the definition suggest a map of the boundary to the unit  sphere? This works in all dimensions, but start by drawing a picture of a planar starlike set and a small circle around its center.